# result of operator = is not static

Tags: case, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am trying to execute this module where an input "ins15_0" enters and if certain conditions are meet it will run the its respective code however when checking syntax  i get the following error on the if lines "result of operator = is not static."

```
lw : if (ins15_0 = "000000000110000") generate
   step_1 : for i in 0 to 31 generate
                    DFF1 : DFF_MEM port map (D=>din(i),clk=>CLK ,Q=>Q(i), reset=> Reset);
            end generate step_1;   
    dout <= x"00000" + q;
end generate lw;

sw : if (ins15_0 = "000000000110100") generate
    step_2 : for i in 0 to 31 generate
                        DFF2 : DFF_MEM port map (D=>rt(i),clk=>CLK ,Q=>Q(i), reset=> Reset);
            end generate step_2;

            dout <= rt;
end generate sw;
```

Comment: `Case` is a sequential statement, you are using it in the parallel region. Use `if ... generate` instead (you can nest generates).

Comment: i tried using if, elsifs however it acts up with the port map, gives me the error  "parse error, unexpected PORT, expecting OPENPAR or TICK or LSQBRACK"

Comment: there is no `elsif` in `if ... generate`. What are you REALLY doing?

Comment: i meant i did it aside, its not in the code posted however when replacing case with if/elsifs it complains about the port maps in the ifs, gives me the error "parse error, unexpected PORT, expecting OPENPAR or TICK or LSQBRACK", added code with ifs instead of case

Comment: I did not suggest `if ... then` which is another sequential statement and can only be used inside a process, where you cannot instantiate components.

Comment: sorry didnt know about if... generate, researched a bit and figured out how it works however it complains about my equal signs, this cant be used? error "result of operator = is not static."

Comment: If `ins15_0` is a signal not a generic or constant (and its declaration is missing) then obviously "generate" won't work. You can't generate and destroy hardware when runtime values change. This is not the way to learn the basics of VHDL but you need a clearer idea what you are trying to do and how to create hardware to do it, regardless of these language issues. First draw an accurate detailed block diagram of the hardware you want.

Comment: not sure if i am using the right term, ins15_0 is an input to the module, not a signal

Comment: Your code sample isn't a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Comment threads aren't the place to explain what you are doing or what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

**Because you're question has been a moving target this addresses "result of operator = is not static."**

From IEEE Std 1076-2008 (the LRM) 11.8 Generate statements paragraph 11:

> The discrete range in the generate parameter specification of a for
>   generate statement shall be a static discrete range; similarly, each
>   condition in an if generate statement shall be a static expression.

The value of the conditions most be static at elaboration time (globally static). This implies you evaluate one or more constants as expressions, which may be conveyed via generic.

Without seeing the delcaration for `ins15_0`, it appears to be an array type, likely a std_logic_vector and perhaps declared as a signal.

Without seeing more of your design specification it's hard to recommend a solution.

Let's look at the first paragraph of 11.8:

> A generate statement provides a mechanism for iterative or conditional
>   elaboration of a portion of a description.

And knowing precisely what elaboration means might help.

See 14.2 Elaboration of a design hierarchy:

> The elaboration of a design hierarchy creates a collection of
>   processes interconnected by nets; this collection of processes and
>   nets can then be executed to simulate the behavior of the design.

And we can look to the preceding paragraph, paragraph 3 of 14.1 General for the finally bit of enlightment:

> In order to execute a model, the design hierarchy defining the model
>   shall first be elaborated. Initialization of nets (see 14.7.3.4) in
>   the model then occurs. Finally, simulation of the model proceeds.
>   Simulation consists of the repetitive execution of the simulation
>   cycle, during which processes are executed and nets updated.

So generation is essential to preparing a model for execution, meaning the value's depended on for a condition in the if generate statement are required to be known at elaboration time to know how many flip flops are connected in the design hierarchy.  The effect is the same for simulation and synthesis.

The design model hierarchy doesn't change after elaboration.  You haven't as yet provided a design specification that can do that.